# Creating a custom, local Route Task

Tags: arcgis-engine, routing, arcgis-10.1

I'm trying to replicate something similar to the ArcGIS WPF Runtime SDK (C:\ArcGIS\WPF1.0\SDK\Samples\Sample Application\Sample Application.exe) "Routing with Barriers Online" sample with two major modifications ... 
1. I have my own network dataset (created from a feature class using ArcObjects classes)
2. I want it to run locally and not on an ArcGIS server instance. Can I exploit LocalServer for this?

First, can this be done? If so, what is the best approach? I have both the WPF runtime and ArcObjects SDK to work with.

Comment: I did try creating a geoprocessing package according to the following suggestion given to me . . . You have a walkthrough here that takes you step by step through the creation of your first routing geoprocessing package:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/...00000m5000000/

And here is the second part, that completes the picture and shows you how to run it from code:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/...00000m6000000/